# STXXL vector_type does not seem to work

Tags: stxxl

I wanted to try STXXL to find how efficient it is in reading a big data file from the disk.
So i setup the enviornment for using it.
Then i ran this program http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/dementiev/stxxl/tags/1.2.1/algo_2sort__file_8cpp-example.html in VS2010. However the file data was not mapped to the vector_type, in fact it deleted the contents of the file after this statement - vector_type v(&f);
I tried changing from stxxl::file::RDWR to stxxl::file::RDONLY, this time the file content was not deleted, however still the vector_type variable was empty.Request your support to proceed further.
Also, is STXXL used widely in commercial applications?

Best Regards,
Ramki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running a code example from STXXL version 1.2.1, which version have you installed on your system?

Most up-to-date version is "Development 1.4" which comes with many improvements, a comprehensive documentation with a lot of short code examples and runs pretty well - check the official **[STXXL Website](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/)** under "Downloads and Documentation". Using version 1.4 is *highly recommended*.

Please check if your problem still exists on the new "Development 1.4" version. The Installation Process has become much easier - read the Installation and Configuration Part of the Documentation at first.

The official webpage provides a (certainly incomplete) list of Publications,Ongoing and Completed Projects using the STXXL successfully - there is no reason why not using it in an commercial environment.

Comment: Thanks Bobb, it works:-) However, the FAQ section says that from 1.4.0 onwards only 64bit systems are supported. However i compiled it as 32bit and it works fine. So do you think it is wise to go ahead with 1.4.0?

Comment: @user2911470: You're right, only 64-bit systems are fully supported. Of cause you can go ahead with the newest version (1.4.0) if it compiles on your 32bit system.